# rails4.2.7のassets precompileでvendor/assets配下のスタイルシートが読み込めない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

いつもお世話になっております。
ruby on rails4.2.7にて、サイトを開発しております。
development環境では、vendor/assets配下に配置したcssが正常に読み込めているのですが、production環境にすると、読み込めていない状況が発生しております。

http://qiita.com/metheglin/items/c5c756246b7afbd34ae2
こちらのサイトなどを参考に、色々と調査をしてはみたのですが、うまくいかない状況です。

ディレクトリ構成は、下記のような感じです。

```
app
 |-assets
   |-stylesheets
     |-application.scss <-ここでb.cssを@importしている
     |-a.scss
vendor
 |-assets
   |-stylesheets
     |-b.css
```

application.scssでは、下記のような感じでインポートをしています。

```
@import "b.css";
@import "a.scss";
```

`*= require style` などを使わないのは、下記のサイトを参考にディレクトリ構成を作り、bootstrap等も読み込んでいるので、そのミックスイン等を使いたかったからです。
http://qiita.com/natsu871/items/53b38a2543df97df751d

b.cssを、app/assets 配下に持ってきて、scssに拡張子を変更すると、production環境でも正常に読み込めてはいるのですが、vendor配下に置いておきたいファイルだったので、ご質問をさせて頂きました。

対応方法と、ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授頂けますと幸いでございます。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

development環境でうまく動いているのはなぜなのか分かりませんが、config/application.rbでassets.pathsにvendorディレクトリを追加してみてはいかがでしょうか

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'stylesheets')
```

### 参考

> In Rails 4.0, precompiling assets no longer automatically copies non-JS/CSS assets from vendor/assets and lib/assets. Rails application and engine developers should put these assets in app/assets or configure config.assets.precompile.
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

---

> Besides the standard assets/* paths, additional (fully qualified) paths can be added to the pipeline in config/application.rb
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘頂きましたように、config/application.rb に追加をしてみましたが、やはりvendor/assets/stylesheets 配下のcssは、読み込めませんでした。